# SWF wrapper in c#?

Tags: c#, flash, wrapper

i have a SWF file with a simple function that returns a string. can i use it in c#? is there any .NET wrapper to flash files that allows "talking" to it?

Comment: I don't guess so. If the function is as simple, as you write, I would re-implement it in C#.

Comment: The function will not be simple. it's a test fucntion for a much complex flash capability function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any readymade wrappers, but it is pretty simple to set up communication between C# and Flash, here's a good blog post on how to do it:

http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/tag/external-interface/